# Angular Router Doesn't Display My Component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, lazy-loading, angular2-routing

I have a Simple Angular 2 App with a Module(InformationPagesModule module) that contains two lazy load components (Info1 Component and Info2 Component). I want to load that components when entering the following routes in the browser:

http://localhost:4200/info1 - Loads the Info1Component

http://localhost:4200/info2 - Loads the Info2Component

here the interest classes:

**app.component.html**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { InformationPagesModule } from './information-pages/information-pages.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    SharedModule,
    InformationPagesModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path:'', component: HomeComponent},
  {path:'info1', loadChildren: './information-pages/information-pages.module#InformationPagesModule'},
  {pathMatch:'full', path:'info2', loadChildren: './information-pages/information-pages.module#InformationPagesModule'},
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],

})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**information-pages.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { InformationPagesRoutingModule } from './information-pages-routing.module';
import { Info1Component } from './info1/info1.component';
import { Info2Component } from './info2/info2.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    InformationPagesRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [Info1Component, Info2Component]
})
export class InformationPagesModule { }
```

**information-pages-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { Info1Component } from './info1/info1.component';
import { Info2Component } from './info2/info2.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path:'info1', component: Info1Component},
  {path:'info2', component: Info2Component}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class InformationPagesRoutingModule { }
```

My question is, why when entering some of the routes / info1 or / info2, a blank page is displayed?

How should I configure the routes in my application so that it works?

Many Thanks!

Comment: Can u create stackblitz example please ?

Comment: Can you try to remove the last `{ path: '**', redirectTo: '' }` 
Also, if you are using  the newest version of Angular, you should change the way you loadChildren: https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules#add-another-feature-module

Comment: I have problems with the routes in stackblitz

Comment: Im try to remove the last { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }, but not working the same problem. Im using angular 2

Answer (score 2):

In your **app-routing.module.ts** you want to declare one parent route to all routes of one lazy loaded module. That means you might want to map all routes starting with */info* to your **information-pages-routing.module.ts**. The routes to your components (info1 and info2) you'll declare inside the lazy loaded module.

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path:'', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'info', loadChildren: './information-pages/information-pages.module#InformationPagesModule' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],

})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

The file **information-pages-routing.module.ts** stays the same

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { Info1Component } from './info1/info1.component';
import { Info2Component } from './info2/info2.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path:'info1', component: Info1Component},
  {path:'info2', component: Info2Component}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class InformationPagesRoutingModule { }
```

You'll now be able to access the **Info1Component** by the route */info/info1* and the **Info2Component** by the route */info/info2*. If you wish to access your compoents by the routes */info1* and */info2* you can either create two lazy loaded modules or just redirect */info1* to */info/info1*

---

You might also consider loading child modules like this:

```
{ path: 'info', loadChildren: () => import('./information-pages/information-pages.module').then(m => m.InformationPageModule) }
```

Rather than

```
{ path: 'info', loadChildren: './information-pages/information-pages.module#InformationPagesModule' }
```

For more information please refer to the official documentation https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules

Answer (score -1):

Use this way instead of using module level routing, use AppRoutingModule for routing your components.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { Info1Component } from './info1/info1.component';
import { Info2Component } from './info2/info2.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path:'', component: HomeComponent},
  {path:'info1', component: Info1Component},
  {path:'info2', component: Info2Component},
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],

})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

If you use this information-pages-routing.module.ts is not required any more.

Comment: I need to use a lazy loading for that